# fontawesome breaks in google chrome with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I have angular 8 application.

and in localhost if I start the application . it breaks every time on a file:

```
use.fontawesome.com/5698ab9788.js.
```

and this is the complete file:

```
window.FontAwesomeCdnConfig = {
  autoA11y: {
    enabled: true
  },
  asyncLoading: {
    enabled: true
  },
  reporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  useUrl: "use.fontawesome.com",
  faCdnUrl: "https://cdn.fontawesome.com:443",
  code: "5698ab9788"
};
```

and this three errors are appearing:

```
5698ab9788.js:15 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/hepchat/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
c @ 5698ab9788.js:15
(anonymous) @ 5698ab9788.js:15
(anonymous) @ 5698ab9788.js:15
h.load @ 5698ab9788.js:15
(anonymous) @ 5698ab9788.js:15
(anonymous) @ 5698ab9788.js:15
2index.html:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/hepchat/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

So my question is how, fix this errors? Thank you

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you check the folder? Is there a file called `fontawesome-webfont.woff2` in the `assets/hepchat/fonts/` folder?

Comment: Thank you. There isn't. See updated post